# Remove quotes Json with Angular

Tags: css, json, angular, string, quotes

I call to front-end with Angular through the pipe {{item.name | json}} data of type "string" from a json file, how do I remove the quotes with CSS or JS? I see "NameA" but I would like see NameA without quotes.

Exemple of json:

people = [{name: "NameA", name: "NameB"}]

Thanks to those who can give me support

Comment: What does your html look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json pipe returns the json-representation of the variable, which contains quotes.

If you simply want to output the string, get rid of the json pipe and use `{{ item.name }}`.